# How to change url of views exposed filter, where will be send a request

Tags: views, javascript, uri

I need to change a request in javascript of views exposed filter.
I want send value clean url arguments in the exposed filter.

I have a part of code but it doesnt work. 
Will be gratefull for the help.

`Drupal.behaviors.DoCategoriesForm = {
attach: function (context, settings) {
var categories = settings.drucity_do.categories;`

$('select.do-advert-category', context).once('DoCategoriesForm', function () {
var form = $(this).parents('form');
$(this).attr('name', '');
$(this).change(function() {
var value = $(this).val();
$(form).attr('action', categories[value]);
});
});
}

Comment: Help me please,
onsubmit is an event of the <form> element and not of the submit button.